# hibernate query multiple object select

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a entity model like this:

```
public class Facture implements Serializable 
{
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ_FACTURE")
private long idFacture;
...

private Panier panier;
    ...
 }

 public class Panier
 {
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ_PANIER")
private long idPanier;  

@ManyToOne
private Client client;
@OneToMany
private List<LignePanier> articles = new ArrayList<LignePanier>();
...
 }

 public class Client
 {
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ_CLIENT")
private long idClient;
...
  }
```

So I would like to query all the facture from a client X.
I try something like this:

```
 public List<Facture> listeFacture(Long clientID) {
    List<ParameterMap> parameters = new ArrayList<ParameterMap>();
    parameters.add(new ParameterMap(StandardBasicTypes.LONG, clientID));
    return dao.query("select facture from Facture facture where facture.panier.client.idClient = ?", parameters);
}
```

I get this exception:

```
  org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: client of: be.infoserv.web.model.Facture [select facture from be.infoserv.web.model.Facture facture where facture.panier.client.idClient = ?]
```

I think it's not possible to query throuth object like this but i don't know how to write this query...

Sorry for my english, i am a french user.

Comment: Do you have proper getter and setters in place??

Comment: Yes i have all getter and setters in place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to use inner joins to do this:

```
select facture
from Facture facture
     inner join facture.panier as panier
     inner join panier.client as client
where client.clientId = ?
```

Or use criteria which can be a bit safer since you can't muck up the hql:

```
Criteria factureCrit = session.createCriteria(Facture.class);
Criteria panierCrit = factureCrit.createCriteria("panier");
Criteria clientCrit = panierCrit.createCriteria("client");
clientCrit.add(Restrictions.idEq(clientId));

return factureCrit.list();
```

Comment: I think your idea is good but i have this exception when i use a join in the query... stupid hibernate xD!

    java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromJoinElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:396)
 at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.joinElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3671)

Comment: you could also try "inner join fetch" as well, which might help.  But the idea is the same.  i use this construct all the time.  However, you might be better off with a criteria query. See the edit

Comment: Thanks for your help, when i have a @manyToOne mapping on panier in class facture all your solution work! But i don't want this mapping because i would like to freeze the state of my bill.

So i finaly do it programmaticaly not so good but it works.

I mark your your response as answer ;)